# Riddle Poem Two

Tags: riddle, pattern, poetry

My first poem’s response was poor. 
Perhaps solving it was a bore, 
But I do not feel sore 
Because I find it fun, 
And I’ve plenty more 
For you to explore 
Like this one! 
Although a bit of a chore 
Matching the rhyme to score, 
The puzzle scheme’s the core 
So get your butt up off the floor, 
And practice up your lore. 
To Puzzling Stack you’ll stun, 
When your answer’s won, 
So don’t grimace in rancor, 
And answer fast, ______! 
Now’s your chance for grandeur, 
Your up-votes will be overrun 
With your answer above done. 
And your loving fans adore 
The elegance of its lure. 


Fill in the blank or 
Tell me what it could be.

Comment: Yes, lure does not technically rhyme with poor, sore, chore, etc... but it's the best I could come up with. Let's all pretend it does!

Comment: Are "grandeur" and "amour" also meant to rhyme with all those -ore things? I assumed those and "lure" were meant to be a separate rhyme ending.

Comment: Yeah, I had to get creative.. only so many things rhyme with one another on so many lines.

Comment: How about "and your loving fans adore", to fix at least one of them? (“Amour” isn’t even a verb, after all.)

Comment: Nice, love the update. Making the change.

Comment: There, I just edited the poem to make it easier to see it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here goes...

I've got the pattern figured out thanks to the recent edit, but I'm still unsure about the actual answer.

The pattern:

> If you assume that A=1, B=2, and so forth, the poem is written with rhymes following the "look and say" pattern, whereby each successive number (or stanza in this case) is how you would say the previous one. For example, the number 12 would be said "one one and one two," therefore the next number would be 1112.  The actual pattern in the poem is: 1, 11, 21, 1211, 111221, _12211, 13... making the missing number a 3. This means that it should rhyme with the "C" type lines, and the only other one we have ends in "be".

My problem:

> I can't think of anything indicative of the pattern that rhymes with "be". Wikipedia tells be that it is also known as the "Cuckoo's Egg" and was developed by John Conway, but neither of these rhyme.  There is, however, a similar sequence called the "pea pattern".

So my answer is:

> "It's (almost) Pea"

Edit: Fixed some sentence errors.

Comment: Excellent work noticing the [Look-And-Say Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Look-and-say_sequence)! It's possible that the OP didn't have a specific word in mind, which is why they wrote "fill in the blank or tell me what it could be" rather than explicitly asking for a missing word.

Comment: Also, FYI, I don't think you need to add in-answer edit updates, especially on so recent a post. The edit history is saved and open for all to view in the edit link.

Comment: Yeah, I nearly put my own name as the answer just because it fit!  I figured I would grasp at something related just in case :)

Answer (score 4):

How about

> PSE user Rand al'Thor

because

> I picked something relevant to PSE that fit the rhyme. It was either going to end with "-one" or "-or," and I went with the latter because it is better represented by other lines of the poem.

Other things that fit:

> numbers that end with 'four', i.e. "And answer fast, twenty four!
>  fire door
>  nevermore
>  commodore
>  etc.
>  I found Rand al'Thor to be the most relevant.

Comment: Thanks :-D But this might need a better explanation for how it fits the riddle ...

Comment: I think the puzzle is in figuring out which set of lines it’s going to rhyme with, though?

Comment: If that was the case, a pattern tag would be appropriate

Comment: Pattern tag added, but think before you start making 50/50 guesses. If it were that easy it wouldn't be much of a riddle.

Answer (score 0):

*Oh boy*, lets see...

> Heretofore? Theretofore? Before? Evermore? M'lord? Sophomore? Mi amor? I implore? Señor? Explore? Build rapport? **LABRADOR? STEGOSAUR?!**

There's far too many possible answers to narrow down just one. Might try again if none of these fit but, I reiterate, *oh boy*.

Comment: I'm afraid you've not figured out the riddle to the riddle.

Comment: Due to the fact that I don't have the reputation to comment on anything that isn't my own answer, I'll have to ask you here @mkinson
Is the 'but' in line 11 purposely misspelled? Additionally, should the 'lure' in line 21 be 'allure'?

Comment: Supposed to be butt, nice catch. And lure is fine, as it is a synonym to entice, though it's the rhyme that matters more than the word itself. Allure would have worked just as well.

Comment: My point exactly. When pronounced, 'allure' has the ... somewhat -ore sound ending the rhyme has been following, whereas 'lure', at least where I'm from, sounds more like -err. Regardless, they both get the point across. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: The "lure" in the word "allure" is pronounced identically to the word lure.